# Running a shell script for a certain duration

Tags: linux, bash, shell, time

I want to be able to run a script on Linux shell (bash) for a certain duration and sleep for a different duration. I've written something like the following snippet. However, I see only the sleep happening correctly but the execution stops after first execution.

```
#!/bin/bash
some_work(){
    echo "Working for $1 minutes"
    if [ $1 -gt 0 ]
        then
            echo "Setting timer for $1 minutes"
            run_end_time=$(($1 * 60))
            start_time=SECONDS
            curr_time=SECONDS
            while $((curr_time < $((start_time + run_end_time)) )) :
                do
                    #Do some work here
                    curr_time=SECONDS
                done
    fi
}

sleep_time(){
    echo "Sleeping for $1 minutes"
    sleep $(($1 * 60))
}

if [ $# -gt 1 ]
    then
        echo "Starting Steeplechase run for $1/$2" 
        while :
            do
                some_work $1
                sleep_time $2
        done
fi
```

The response I get is ./script.sh: line 30: 1: not found. Maybe I'm missing something bigtime here.

Comment: It should be `while (( ... )); do` instead of `while $(( ... )); do`. And the colon at the end of that line should be a `;` (or can be removed, like all your semicolons).

Comment: This [web page](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html0) gives some examples

Comment: @Benjamin W. I edited the snippet to reflect your suggestion but not finding difference in the behavior.

Comment: @vmachan, The link you shared seems to be broken.

Comment: Well, the main suggestion was to remove the outer `$` in the `while $(( ... ))` line and to remove the colon at the end of that line.

Comment: I did it and now I get ./script.sh line 30:  can't open 120: no such file
./script.sh libe 30: curr_time: not found

Comment: Corrected [link](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html).. sorry somehow a zero got suffixed to the link in the previous comment,

Comment: @Benjamin W. Thanks the script is now running fine.

Comment: @vmachan thanks. The link helped with the similar suggestions too. Might come handy while trying scripts with loops in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

- The conditional construct is `while (( ... )); do` and not `while $(( ... )); do`
- The colon at the end of your line

  ```
  while $((curr_time < $((start_time + run_end_time)) )) :
  ```

  must not be there.
- You're assigning the string `SECONDS` when you want the value of the variable; the assignments should look like `var=$SECONDS` instead of `var=SECONDS`.

Complete script, with a few suggestions and my idea of indentation:

```
#!/bin/bash

some_work () {
    echo "Working for $1 minutes"
    if (( $1 > 0 )); then
        echo "Setting timer for $1 minutes"
        run_end_time=$(($1 * 60))
        start_time=$SECONDS
        curr_time=$start_time  # Want this to be the same value
        while ((curr_time < $((start_time + run_end_time)) )); do
            #Do some work here
            curr_time=$SECONDS
        done
    fi
}

sleep_time () {
    echo "Sleeping for $1 minutes"
    sleep $(($1 * 60))
}

if (( $# > 1 )); then
    echo "Starting Steeplechase run for $1/$2"
    while true; do
        some_work $1
        sleep_time $2
    done
fi
```